# How to get value from SingleOrDefaultValue if it throw InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#

i face some issue. Me need to log which Id throw InvalidOperationException, for example campaignIDsRange collection contains two dublicates (12,12), how i can log this number

```
                try
                {
                    dashboardItems.AddRange(
                        campaignIdsRange.Select(
                            campaignId => dashboardItemsRange.SingleOrDefault(x => x.campaign_id == campaignId));
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                {
                  
                    _logger.Warning(, e);
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
```

Comment: Use `.Where`, look at the number of results returned

Comment: You'll have to do the validation in a separate step. `var dups = dashboardItemsRange.GroupBy(x => x.campaign_id == campaignId).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(y => y.campaign_id).ToList();` and then see if the list is empty.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thank you, how the intermediate step looks good

Answer (score 2):

You can put your try block inside the Select method.

```
dashboardItems.AddRange(
    campaignIdsRange
        .Select(campaignId => 
        {
            try
            {
                return dashboardItemsRange.SingleOrDefault(x => x.campaign_id == campaignId);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                _logger.Warning(, e);
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        });
```

Comment: "need to log which Id throw InvalidOperationException"